# Moodle 2: users are not getting ticks and scores in the navigation tree.

Tags: navigation, dashboard, moodle

Moodle 2: We are investigating a problem where some users are not getting ticks and scores in the navigation tree when they have finished activities. Since we have not been able to replicate the issue by logging is to the affected users accounts, we have concluded that this stems from the end-users systems.

Is this the right way to test? Can anyone suggest why this problem is happening? Thanks -G

Comment: This one would probbaly be more suited to the Moodle.org forums, as it's not really a code problem and the people who use the Moodle activities a lot may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs on the users' systems but not when you log in as them to check then it may be due to some completion events requiring the cron script to run. You could try making this run more frequently.